# Dropbox process gets killed right after startup

Tags: dropbox

I have a Windows 7 computer with three accounts. One for me, for my wife and one for my son. Mine and my wife's are administrator, my son's is a normal user.

We all use Dropbox. There is a problem under my wife's account. She cannot start Dropbox. Not by clicking the shortcut, and not by going into her user folder with cmd.exe and type dropbox.exe. And the Dropbox shortcut in her Startup folder is also ineffective so it does not startup automatically after logon.

The dropbox.exe process is alive for about half a second. And then gets killed off.
If she starts Dropbox explicitly with "run as administrator" it starts fine and stays alive. It's a pain for her to have to remember to manually start Dropbox in this way every time. And I find myself fixing her conflicted copies all the time. Under my own and my son's account Dropbox works fine. Uninstall/install did not have any effect.

How can I find out why the process gets killed? Does Dropbox kill itself? Does it leave any logging anywhere? Is there some kind of tracing level that I can set to a more sensitive value to debug this? Or do you think an other program is responsible for killing dropbox? How could I find out which one that would be?

Comment: Which version number of Dropbox are you using on the account with the problem? Does she have `Include me on early releases` checked in Dropbox settings (on the website)?

Comment: Now, after re-installation she has 2.6.27.0. Before it was 2.4.11.0, like it still is under my account. She had/has this problem with both versions. Include me on early releases is unchecked. She has Spanish language set and I use English, but that shouldn't be a problem right?